# Logic app workflow continues to publish messages even after being deleted from the portal

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

Logic app workflow continues to publish messages even after being deleted from the portal
It seems to be in some sort of infinite loop that's continuously publishing messages.
I retried recreating a workflow with the same name but it wont let me save anything in the codeview.

Comment: Can you check if there are any instances of the logic app present in your resource group?

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to any of the following reasons:

- Might have deleted the wrong workflow
- Loops(connectors that are triggering outside the logic app) inside the workflow (i.e.. Similar to Deadlock Concept).

We can actually have a look at which workflow is actually triggering from the logs. Enabling/ Adding Diagnostics settings for the logic app to either Log Analytics workspace/ Storage Account/ Event hub/ Partner solution allows us to review the logs.

For this, I've set up a log analytics workspace. Here are the steps to logging all of your activity from the logic app to the log analytics workspace. [Enabling Log Analytics In Logic App](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/enabling-log-analytics-in-logic-app)

Try using the `requests;` query of your logic app to know which workflow is actually triggering.

[image]